# How can I call bash from C with a clean environment?

Tags: c, linux

I'm attempting to set up my computer such that I can authenticate myself using an external device connected to a python script. I started by replacing the `login` program in `inittab` with my own program, and I've been able to get into a bash shell. The problem is that it doesn't get a fresh environment like the one that is (I presume) given with `login`. I know there are ways for me to mess with the environment, but i haven't seen a way to give it a "default" configuration, if even such a thing makes sense.

Comment: Have you looked through the source for `login`? That's the first place I'd look. There are probably quite a number of things a `login` program needs to do that you wouldn't be able to guess.

Comment: Also, you might consider writing a [`pam` module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_authentication_module) instead of replacing the `login` program entirely.

Comment: @GregHewgill I thought about that, but i couldn't find the source for it. I don't even know where to start looking

Comment: Well, I guess that depends on which Linux distribution you are using. They all keep their source code in different places. If you were using FreeBSD, I could point you directly at it: http://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/usr.bin/login/login.c?revision=221374&view=markup

Comment: Have you started a login shell?  Classically, you'd give it an `argv[0]` such as `-bash`, but there's also the `bash -l` option to make `bash` go through the system and user profiles.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes.

Comment: Apparently this is done by clearing the environment completely, and setting each variable more-or-less by hand.

Comment: You can get a fresh environment for the `bash` shell via `env -i USER=user HOME=/home/user PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin bash -l`. You really only need to set the `USER`, `HOME`, and `PATH` environment variables; plus `LANGUAGE`, `LANG`, and `LC_ALL` or other `LC_` ones if you want some locale other than the default POSIX/C one; `TERM` (and `-i` option to `bash`) if interactive or use a terminal, and `DISPLAY` if using X11. But honestly, a `PAM` module is a much easier option. It's not nearly as hard to write the module as you might think.

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas:

First of all it would be better in most cases to use the pluggable login architecture PAM. This will ensure, that all PAM-enabled applications and services can use the authentification method (ssh for example) and that there is no way to bypass it using regular services.

If you really want to replace `login` i'd suggest to clear the environment by yourselves using [`unsetenv`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/unsetenv) for each environment variable set (you may use [`environ`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/environ) to determine the variables already set). After cleaning up the environment you may use a `exec`-like call to replace your program with a `bash`, the environment will be unchanged in this context. You may want to add the command line argument `-l` to start up bash as it would have been invoked by `login`.

Bash is running some init scripts on startup. You may check `/etc/profile`, `/etc/bashrc` and similar files for environment variables you don't want to be set.

If you want to be dependant on [`env`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/env) (wich is not so bad, since it should be present on every linux system out there) you can use `env -i bash`to call bash in a clean environment.

Answer (score 0):

When main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]) is called by the operating system, the third parameter contains the environment. So just save a copy of it until you need to call bash.

Comment: I don't want to preserve the environment, i want to destroy it.